# C++ stdlib map::at function not working like I expect for struct key

Tags: c++, stl, maps

I'm programming an assignment for my algorithms class. I have a struct

```
struct Node
{
    int firstPosition;
    int secondPosition;
    string firstColor;
    string secondColor;

    bool operator<(const Node& n) const {
        return (firstPosition < n.secondPosition);
    }

    bool operator==(const Node& n) const {
        return (firstPosition == n.firstPosition && secondPosition == n.secondPosition && firstColor == n.firstColor && secondColor == n.secondColor);
    }
};
```

I have an stl map called "graph"

```
map<Node, vector<Node>> graph;
```

I place a single node in to start the building of the graph

```
Node startNode = {1, 1, "R", "B"};
vector<Node> emptyVector;
graph.emplace(startNode, emptyVector);
```

I'm essentially trying to build a graph of nodes, so for every line of input I get (class gave me an input file - sourceNode and targetNode are integers I read in, pathColor is a string I read in), I need to access each node and add other nodes to their adjacency list based on what I read in, so in a while loop for each line:

```
 for (auto& currentNode : graph) {
            // Case: sourceNode is the first position, so we make a new node with the updated first position
            if (currentNode.first.firstPosition == sourceNode ) {
                if (currentNode.first.secondColor == pathColor) {
                    Node newNode = {targetNode, currentNode.first.secondPosition, vertexColors[targetNode - 1], currentNode.first.secondColor};
                    graph.at(currentNode.first).emplace_back(newNode);  // Put the newly created node in the current node's adjacency list
                    vector<Node> emptierVector;
                    graph.emplace(newNode, emptierVector);              // Insert the newly created node into the graph
                }
            }
// More extra code down below
```

But the graph.at(currentNode.first).emplace_back(newNode); line throws "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  map::at" even though I've implemented the == operator overload and verified it works and that my data matches. I can't seem to find where my misunderstanding of the function works from documentation. Please help!

I'm expecting the map.at(key) function to return the key's associated data, but when I am passing it a struct here with the exact same data as the key, it throws an out of range instead of returning the value associated with the key. Can I not just pass a struct with the exact same data as the key? It seems to not detect as the same key value.

Comment: The exception is because `graph.at(currentNode.first)` doesn't add new elements to `graph` (a good thing because adding new elements so would break the range-`for`). That said, since `currentNode` came from `graph` something is already broken. Me, I'd suspect `graph.emplace(newNode, emptierVector);` is probably the bad boy, adding to a container while it's being iterated by range `for`. You can insert to a `map` without damaging iterators, but I'm not sure what it does to the map's end.

Comment: I think there's a good question in here, but we need more information, [mre] would be nice, to help pry an answer out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the way the map.at() function works, it was that my less than operator in my struct was declared incorrectly. It compared different values from two Nodes instead of the same value.
This website helped me realize.
https://www.techiedelight.com/use-custom-objects-keys-std-map-cpp/